# how to get content using web scraper in java

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, jsoup

need your help to build an application in java/J2EE which can work as a Web scraper.

Here is my thought about the project

In my application home page there will be an textbox in which user can enter any URL which they want to access.
After clicking on go button the webpage will be shown under my application i.e. URL will remain same of my application.
User can input anything in the textboxes on webpage and click on the respective action (search/submit).
On form submit of that page I can capture the text that user has placed in the textbox and save it in my database.
That's it.

Now the problem is if I am looking at some already available java based Web Scrapers like WebHarvest, they simply capture the predefined strings on the URL.

Please help me in finding some tutorial or any Open Source application which can work for me after some modifications

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide you with simple **Selenium WebDriver in Java**. Yet all the details you may find [here](https://webscraping.pro/how-to-use-selenium-webdriver-with-java/).

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class WebScraper {

    public WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    /**
     * Open the test website.
     */
    public void openTestSite() {
        driver.navigate().to("http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/login");
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param username
     * @param Password
     * 
     *            Logins into the website, by entering provided username and
     *            password
     */
    public void login(String username, String Password) {

        WebElement userName_editbox = driver.findElement(By.id("usr"));
        WebElement password_editbox = driver.findElement(By.id("pwd"));
        WebElement submit_button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Login']"));

        userName_editbox.sendKeys(username);
        password_editbox.sendKeys(Password);
        submit_button.click();

    }

    /**
     * grabs the status text and saves that into status.txt file
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void getText() throws IOException {
        String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='case_login']/h3")).getText();
        Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("status.txt"), "utf-8"));
        writer.write(text);
        writer.close();

    }

    /**
     * Saves the screenshot
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void saveScreenshot() throws IOException {
        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("screenshot.png"));
    }

    public void closeBrowser() {
        driver.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        WebScraper webSrcaper = new WebScraper();
        webSrcaper.openTestSite();
        webSrcaper.login("admin", "12345");
        webSrcaper.getText();
        webSrcaper.saveScreenshot();
        webSrcaper.closeBrowser();
    }
}
```

Some other [scrape related tools](https://webscraping.pro/tag/java/) on Java.